# I am creating Subscription for new email arrivals but the Microsoft Graph API is not Creating Subscription

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

**Code For Subscription**

```
var requestBody = new Subscription  { 
   ChangeType = "created,updated", 
   NotificationUrl =  "https://localhost:7230/Notification", 
   Resource = $"users/'{resultUsers.Value.FirstOrDefault().Id}'/mailFolders('inbox')/messages", 
   ExpirationDateTime = System.DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15), 
   ClientState = clientSecret, LatestSupportedTlsVersion = "v1_2",  
}; 
var result = await graphClient.Subscriptions.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

**Code For GraphClient**

```
  public GraphServiceClient MsGraphService()
  {
      //var scopes = "User.Read Mail.Read";
      //var scopesArray = scopes.Split(' ');
      var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
      {
          AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
      };
      var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
          tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
      GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

      return graphServiceClient;
  }
```

**Exeption Am getting**

> Unable to connect to the remote server

I have tried to change resource in the requestBody i think it could be the problem but still confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error

> Unable to connect to the remote server

Means that Graph can't connect to your Webhook endpoint which seems to be

> NotificationUrl =  "https://localhost:7230/Notification",

The cloud can't connect back to https://localhost so this needs to be a public accessible endpoint, you can use something like ngrok in testing to do this have a look at the bottom of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoftgraph/nodejs-webhooks-sample/microsoft-graph-webhooks-sample-for-nodejs/?source=recommendations which goes through doing this.